# Auto run GUI application on startup

Tags: vnc, lxde, chroot, jdownloader

I've set up an Ubuntu `chroot` on my NAS (a Synology DS214play) to run `JDownloader 2`. I've installed vnc4server and set it up to run on NAS startup and it works smoothly.
I've installed `LXDE` which starts along with VNC server and it's working too. But auto run of `JDownloader 2` on startup seems to not be working. I tried several ways to make it run but none seemd to have effect.

So can someone please list ALL the ways a GUI app can be set to auto run on startup so i can try them all?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Here a list of my attempts.

**1)** Created a `jd2.desktop` file placed inside `/volume1/ubuntu/root/.config/autostart` containing this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=JDownloader 2
Exec=/bin/sh "/usr/local/jd2/JDownloader2"
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=false
```

I also tried with `Exec=/usr/local/jd2/JDownloader2`

**2)** Same file but placed inside `/volume1/ubuntu/etc/xdg/autostart`

**3)** Tried adding line to exectue it after starting lxde inside `/volume1/ubuntu/root/.vnc/xstartup` file and inside `/volume1/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup` file

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

#[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
#[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
#xsetroot -solid grey
#vncconfig -iconic &
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
startlxde &
lxsession
/bin/sh "/usr/local/jd2/JDownloader2"
```

Also tried with this in those files:

```
/usr/local/jd2/JDownloader2 &
```

**4)** Tried to add line to `/volume1/ubuntu/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` file:

```
@/bin/sh "/usr/local/jd2/JDownloader2"
```

Also tried with:

```
@/usr/local/jd2/JDownloader2
```

The strange thing is that if i place `@lxterminal` it works (it does start 2 Terminal windows, dont know why 2 instead of 1)

Comment: Better do it the other way around. Pleas tell us exactly what you did.

Comment: A simple Google search turns up this related advice: http://steven-england.info/2014/11/23/setting-raspberry-pi-download-station-help-jdownloader2/

Comment: @JacobVlijm edited with all methods i tried to use

Comment: @ElderGeek tried with method from the page you linked but it didnt work

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to add clarity in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To autostart JDownloader together with a specific user’s session, create this script in your preferred users home (hereafter referred to as /home/username)

`nano /home/username/jdownloader2/startjd2.sh`

with the JDownloader init command in it:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -jar /home/username/jdownloader2/JDownloader.jar
```

Set the correct permissions afterwards:

`chmod 755 /home/username/jdownloader2/startjd2.sh`

Then edit

`nano /home/username/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`

and put this line into this usually empty file:

`@/home/username/jdownloader2/startjd2.sh`

If you want a desktop icon press

lxshortcut -o /home/username/Desktop/JDownloader.desktop

and tell the wizard the path to your startjd2.sh

Comment: I tried that when i read your comment but it didnt work, i tried also the same method but replacing `java -jar` command with `/usr/local/jd2/JDownloader2` in the startjd2.sh script and it did not work either

Comment: @Fabius If you could be a bit more specific than "it didn't work" I might have more to say.

Comment: I folowed all the steps of that method and JDownloader does not start along with LXDE, while adding lines like "@lxterminal" or "@firefox" makes them start with no problem. I dont know if there's any log to look at to see what's wrong with JDownloader.

Comment: what is the output of `which java`

Comment: You need to insure it's installed and on your path...